# Help with subfigure

Tags: graphics, subfloats

Hi I would like to use \subfigure in order to have the a figure with 6 subfigures ordered as follows:

[image]

where (a1) (a2) ... (c1) (c2) should be the figure name not the caption! (I forgot the  brackets in the exampe!)
Thank you so much!

Comment: Ordered how? :o)

Comment: You should use the `\usepackage{subfig}` instead of the obselete `\usepackage{subfigure}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `subfigure` package is deprecated; you should use either the `subfig` or the `subcaption` package.

Here's a solution based on the capabilities of the `subcaption` package. Each `subfigure` environment is assigned a width of `0.3\textwidth` to have some whitespace between adjacent subfigures.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real file
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{subfiga1}
\caption*{a1}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill} % note: no blank line
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{subfigb1}
\caption*{b1}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill} % note: no blank line
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{subfigc1}
\caption*{c1}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{subfiga2}
\caption*{a2}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill} % note: no blank line
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{subfigb2}
\caption*{b2}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill} % note: no blank line
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{subfigc2}
\caption*{c2}
\end{subfigure}

%%\caption{Overall caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much but: (a1) (a2) ... (c1) (c2) should be the figure name not the caption...

Comment: @Kevin - I've modified the example code: to address the requirement expressed in your comment, it suffices to replace `\caption` with `\caption*`. (To get parentheses around the captions, just place them in the argument of `\caption*`.)